# None type in _init_ method

Tags: python

I am beginner  in python. I cant understand simple thing  with type None . When I assign None values to my parameters in constructor . I get error. What is the trick . Code with error:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

  def method_a(self, foo):
    if self.root is None:
       print self.root + ' ' + foo


a = A()               # We do not pass any argument to the __init__ method
a.method_a('Sailor!') # We only pass a single argument
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dmitry/PycharmProjects/Algorithms/final_bst.py", line 11, in <module>
    a.method_a('Sailor!') # We only pass a single argument
  File "C:/Users/Dmitry/PycharmProjects/Algorithms/final_bst.py", line 7, in method_a
    print self.root + ' ' + foo
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

As soon as I change None type in *init*  for something like string variable it works correctly.

Comment: What do you expect `None + ' '` to do?  The problem has nothing to do with `__init__` as such; the problem is that you can't add None to a string, as the error message says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate None with two strings ' ' and 'Sailor!', and None is not a String.

Answer (score 2):

The error is **not** in `__init__` but later, in the expression you're trying to `print`:

```
print self.root + ' ' + foo
```

You can use `+` to concatenate strings, but `None` is **not** a string.

So, use string formatting:

```
print '{} {}'.format(self.root, foo)
```

or, far less elegantly, **make** a string explicitly:

```
print str(self.root) + ' ' + foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating `None` with strings. However `None` is not a string, it's an object, if you want to print an object you must use `str(<Obj>)`, this will call the `__str__` method of the object, or
if no `__str__` method is given, the result of `__repr__` will be printed.

The difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).